# Angular 4 is cutting queryParams with hash

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

I'm working in a component which receive a queryParam with two values:

Example:
**http://localhost:4200/start/setup-employee?c=RCS8KR8J&email=test$#myaddress@gmail.com**

The problem is if I get the queryParams the param "c" is ok, but the param "email" only return "test$" because the # cut the param.
Any idea how to solve this? I see that I can get the rest in the fragment, but maybe is another good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ever passing the special ml characters in the url make use of the encodeURIComponent function before passing the value like this

```
encodeURIComponent("test$#myaddress@gmail.com");
```

Output

```
test%24%23myaddress%40gmail.com
```

And do the decide then use the value

```
decodeURIComponent("test%24%23myaddress%40gmail.com");
```

Output

```
test$#myaddress@gmail.com
```

This way no cutting of query parama will happen.
This way you can be safe with all the special characters blocks anytime in the query params.

Comment: Thanks I think this is a good approach. I will move forward with this implementation

Answer (score 1):

This isn't Angular's fault. This is just a behavior of how the urls is handled when we do a http request, some characters can't be used in a queryParam value because that character already has a reserved meaning. Try to replace # with he's hashed value where you assign the value like: `.replace('&', '%26');`.